# Update Task In Android Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am building a TODO list app and using ROOM as my database.

I am trying to update the task from the DAO but it's not changing the object, it's duplicating it instead, like it's a new task.

Furthermore, I tried getting the task by its unique ID and setting it to the updated task, so it can be identified, but it didn't work, this is what I tried:

```
public void updateTask(Task updatedTask, int taskPosition) {
    Task oldTask = appDataBase.taskDao().getTask(taskPosition);
    oldTask = updatedTask;

    int id = oldTask.getTaskID();
    updatedTask.setTaskID(id);
    
    appDataBase.taskDao().updateTask(updatedTask);
}
```

This is the DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDataAccessObject {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task ORDER BY taskPriority")
    List<Task> loadAllTask(); // returns a list of task object

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertTask(Task task);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void updateTask(Task task);

    @Delete
    void deleteTask(Task task);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE taskID = :id")
    Task getTask(int id);


}
```

This is the TASK model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "task")
public class Task {

    @ColumnInfo(name="taskTag")
    private String taskTag;

    @ColumnInfo(name="taskPriority")
    private String taskPriority;

    @ColumnInfo(name="taskDate")
    private String taskDate;

    @ColumnInfo(name="taskTime")
    private String taskTime;

    @ColumnInfo(name="taskName")
    private String taskName;

    @ColumnInfo(name="priorityPosition")
    private int priorityPosition;

    @ColumnInfo(name="tagPosition")
    private int tagPosition;

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int taskID;

    public Task(String taskName, String taskPriority, int priorityPosition, String taskTag, int tagPosition, String taskDate, String taskTime) {

        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
        this.taskTag = taskTag;
        this.taskDate = taskDate;
        this.taskTime = taskTime;
        this.priorityPosition = priorityPosition;
        this.tagPosition = tagPosition;
    }

    public int getTaskID() {
        return taskID;
    }

    public String getTaskTag() {
        return taskTag;
    }

    public String getTaskPriority() {
        return taskPriority;
    }

    public int getTagPosition() {
        return tagPosition;
    }

    public void setTagPosition(int tagPosition) {
        this.tagPosition = tagPosition;
    }

    public String getTaskDate() {
        return taskDate;
    }

    public String getTaskTime() {
        return taskTime;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskID(int taskID) {
        this.taskID = taskID;
    }

    public void setTaskTag(String taskTag) {
        this.taskTag = taskTag;
    }

    public void setTaskPriority(String taskPriority) {
        this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
    }

    public void setTaskDate(Date newDate) {
        this.taskDate = taskDate;
    }

    public void setTaskTime(Date newTime) {
        this.taskDate = taskTime;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public int getPriorityPosition() {
        return priorityPosition;
    }

    public void setPriorityPosition(int priorityPosition) {
        this.priorityPosition = priorityPosition;
    }


}
```

The function with the updated values:

```
rootView.addTaskFinishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Updated Task Values
                String updatedTaskName = rootView.addTaskEditText.getText().toString();
                String updatedTaskPriority = addTaskViewModel.getPriorityAdapter().getPriorityColor();
                int updatedPriorityPosition = addTaskViewModel.getPriorityAdapter().getPriorityPosition();
                String updateTaskTag = addTaskViewModel.getTagsAdapter().getTag();
                int updatedTagPosition = addTaskViewModel.getTagsAdapter().getPriorityPosition();
                String updatedTaskDate = addTaskViewModel.getDateValue();
                String updatedTaskTime = addTaskViewModel.getTimeValue();

                Task updatedTask = new Task(updatedTaskName,updatedTaskPriority,updatedPriorityPosition,updateTaskTag,updatedTagPosition,updatedTaskDate,updatedTaskTime);
                addTaskViewModel.updateTask(updatedTask,taskPosition);

            }
        });
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`new Task()` will do what it says, because `@PrimaryKey` `taskId` is `null`.
While when that object has a `@PrimaryKey` `taskId`, one can update it:

```
public void updateTask(Task task, int position) {
    appDataBase.taskDao().updateTask(task);
}
```

`task.setPosition(position)` makes no sense, because reordering a list would require at least two update queries. It's the [list update problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_update_problem) ...that's why one query doesn't suffice. When assuming a drag/drop ordered list, `taskPriority` should be of data-type `Long`. Add a `@Query` method to DAO, which updates field `taskPriority` by `taskId`, then it's easier to handle; for example:

```
@Query("UPDATE tasks SET priority = :priority WHERE task_id LIKE :taskId")
Long updatePriority(Long taskId, Long priority);
```

For moving items in a list, one needs at least the old and new position of the item to move. This needs to be controlled with a list re-indexing algorithm. A `Task` usually has a `taskListId`, which has to be considered. And `void insertTask(Task task);` should indeed return `Long taskId`.